# Setting up VS 2013 to debug a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C# solution with about 10 projects in it. It is a standard Windows Form application.
I have DLL in a separate directory that compiles fine and work so long as I move the DLL file into the executable directory of the main program.

Now I would like to add some functions to the DLL and debug it.

I have attempted to follow the MS help for How to debug from a DLL project but it is full of errors and cannot be used (3. where or what is the 'Project Property Pages window in the Configuration drop-down' for example).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx

Is there a better reference for a first time user attempting to set breakpoints in a DLL?

Comment: Have you tried adding the pdb to the directory with the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Ignore MS help (it is not) 
Start a project with only the DLL in it
Add a project to that solution that calls the DLL 
Make that new  project the one that starts when you hit run

Its that simple.